# Forge Issues API giving 500 error, the API was working fine till last week now it is showing issues

Tags: autodesk-forge, internal-server-error, forge, autodesk-bim360, autodesk-construction-cloud

I am getting 500(Internal Server Error) in BIM 360 issues APIs since this week which was working fine till last week
APIs are :
"https://developer.api.autodesk.com/issues/v1/containers/+containerId+/quality-issues?page[limit]=100". "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/issues/v1/containers/+containerId+/ng-issue-types?include=subtypes".
But in case of Construction Cloud APIs for BIM 360 issues are working fine.
ChangeLog of BIM 360 issues are also not showing any changes.
Can anyone please guide me what is happening here as our Live APIs are based on BIM 360 API ?

Answer (score 0):

They are moving to a new platform

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve issues for [BIM360](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/field-issues-GET/) and [ACC](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/acc/v1/reference/http/issues-issues-GET/) you need to use different endpoints.